# Unable to access mapped network drive through web application

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, webserver, xampp, owncloud

I configured open source file sharing system call "Owncloud". When the data directory (File saving location) config in the local machine it works perfectly. But when I mapped a network drive and try to configure it on the config file unable to load and display following message.

```
Data directory (Z:\test99\test11) is invalid
Please check that the data directory contains a file ".ocdata" in its root.

Cannot create "data" directory (Z:\test99\test11)
This can usually be fixed by giving the webserver write access to the root directory.
```

Z is a mapped network drive in same LAN network server and I put `.ocdata` file as same as I put on local location. I'm currently work on Windows environment and application is running on Apache server and MySQL DB under "Xampp control panel". Servers are not under AD integrated. Config file edited as below way,
" 'datadirectory' => 'Z:\test99\test11'," .
If I put data directory for local machine location that's works fine. How should I integrate network mapped location?

Comment: Please can you tell us what user the Apache service is running as? I would imagine that it's not running as your user, and thus doesn't share the same network drives that you do...

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you registered and created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.  I'm assuming the proposed edit was from you.

Comment: @Attie I executed ""exec('whoami');"" on Apache server and it displayed as "SYSTEM". Yes I have mapped another server storage and even though it has been mapped, I think it is still belongs to other server. How should I run this mapped network drive as "SYSTEM" user in my environment?